# How to apply for ms in astrophysics?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters

I am a mechanical engineering student from India. I wish to do an ms in astrophysics in foreign universities. How should I apply and what are the requisites for admission in different universities?

Comment: Go to each of the Universities websites and check out the registration procedures. They will all have their own criteria - but some will be similar, level of prior education etc, equivalents with other countries / institutions etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be helpful to have an undergraduate background in Physics (or you have some other science based background and have taken plenty of Physics courses). If that is the case then you might have to take some per-requisite courses to fulfill graduate school requirements of a certain university.

I would start with GRE test. Make sure you score higher on the analytical section than the verbal.

I would go through this journal https://aas.org/ and look for university leaders in Astrophysics. Narrow down your list to 5-7 universities, search through the research professors in Astrophysics at those universities acquaint yourself with their research and then email those professors to make your case. Introduce yourself, inquire them what your interests are and why do you want to pursue a graduate degree in Astrophysics and how you would be interested in joining their research.

Most universities have pretty generic graduate school admission process. Submit application before deadline. Write statement of purpose. Provide GRE scores. Provide reference letters. Pay application fee etc.

I went for graduate school in USA so my advice is particular to admission process for USA graduate programs.

Comment: I think that this answer would be greatly improved by removing the gratuitous assumptions and addressing the question more generally.